# Swift/GTK Bindings

Tags: gtk

We see from [this](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/q/5547/7356)  that there is interest in using Swift to develop apps for elementary OS. There's also experimental GTK bindings available, but I don't think it's being maintained: https://github.com/TomasLinhart/SwiftGtk

I would love to port some of my stuff over to elementary OS and the OSS community at large, but knowing there isn't official GTK support for Swift is a huge setback. I don't want to switch to Vala because I'd have to rewrite thousands of lines of my existing code, and once you get used to a good IDE with strong support for *a language with named parameters* (arguably the best thing about Swift), you never want to go back (code readability skyrockets, in my opinion).

Are there plans from the elementary OS team to officially support Swift? Or do I need to go pester the GTK folks?

Answer (score 1):

There are currently no plans from elementary to officially support Swift. However, apps submitted to AppCenter are more than welcome to use Swift or any other language so long as they are GTK3 apps. If the GTK3 bindings for Swift are or become usable, Swift apps are more than welcome on the platform.

Answer (score 0):

There is [a different GitHub project](https://github.com/rhx/SwiftGtk) ([rhx/SwiftGtk](https://github.com/rhx/SwiftGtk)) described as:

> A Swift wrapper around gtk-3.x & gtk-4.x that is largely auto-generated from gobject-introspection.

It looks to be more complete and up-to-date than the project you found. They have links to sample projects as well.